# Where is Drupal commerce cart page configured

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-commerce

I have a Drupal Panopoly site and I want to add some commerce functionality so I've installed Drupal commerce on my test site. Panopoly, as you may know, is heavily panels based. I've cloned the **Shopping cart** block as a views pane so I can use it in a panel page and that works perfectly.

On this pane there's a **View cart** link which takes you to the page mysite.com/**cart**. That cart link seems to be fixed, I cannot change it to, say, mycart.

My question is how is this cart page defined? I cannot find any page called cart in my site try as I might. There is a view called **Shopping cart form** but (and this shows my lack of knowledge of views), it looks slightly odd not seeming to have a type (block, page, etc). I have tweaked this and, although it doesn't have a page name so, it is what produces the output of the cart page.

I thought that I would clone this form as a views panel to use in a panel page **mycart** but this produces an empty cart.

I've googled and read the commerce information but I can't find anything that explains how this works and what I should be doing to change it.

Can someone please explain how I can use the cart in a panel.

Answer (score 1):

I finally came across this: https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/modifying-shopping-cart-using-views.

I took my cloned version of the **Shopping cart form** view which is a **View Panes**, and simply changed the contextual filter in accordance with the above instructions.

To keep the answer self-contained:

Change the contextual filter to **Provide default value** and select **Current user's cart order ID**.

I now have a pane I can use in a panel.
Seemples!

Answer (score 0):

Cart page is created from the code, and main part of it is a view.

You can easily change view templates - you edit view called "commerce_cart_form", open "Advanced" panel (group, what ever it is) and click on "Theme: Information"... There you can see what template files are used...and you can edit them.

You can also change the view it self...add new fields or something..

Comment: But how do I use it in a panel in a page that I call, say, mycart?